# Stop music via DLNA on incoming call

Tags: calls, music, dlna, pause

I'm searching for a way to pause music playing on my DLNA sound system when a call comes in on my Android phone. Ideally, the music would continue as soon as I hang up my call.

Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: Note: "Is there an app for X" questions are off-topic here – though in your case, it's unlikely to work without a 3rd party app. What you'd need for that is a [DLNA Control Point](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/multimedia_dlna#group_1047) app, plus an [automation app](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_automation), and both must "play together" – so you could setup a rule like "IF incoming-call THEN stop music ON EXIT continue music". Open question remains how to check whether there's music playing at all...